# Replacing the Lowest Score with the Average.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that we have three numbers, $A$, $B$, and $C$, all distinct.

What will happen in the limit if we were to repeat the process of replacing the lowest score with the average of all three, ad infinitum?

To make things easier, we can normalize so that the initial conditions are

$A= 0$, $B=x$, $C=1$, with $0<x<1$.

$C=1$ will stay the same, but $A$ and $B$ will change.

My gut feeling is that both $A$ and $B$ will converge to 1. But how to prove this...?

---

Let $a_n$, $b_n$, and $c_n$ be the sequence of the three numbers, in ascending order.

For now, I will normalize everything so that $a_0 = 0$, $b_0 = b$ and $c_0 = 1$.

It appears from a few numerical computations that

> $a_n = b_{n-1}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

If this is true, then both $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge (basically by the argument provided by TZakrevskiy), and this will force $\lim a_n = \lim b_n = 1$ by arguing that the limits must be stable under the average and drop process.

---

**Edit:** I just realized that $b_n$ should also be a non-decreasing sequence, so the problem is essentially done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will consider the sequence $l_n$, with  $l_n$being equal to the lowest of three numbers at stage $n$.

At each stage, we replace the lowest of three numbers by the average of those three numbers - therefore, the sequence is non-decreasing. Moreover, this sequence is obviously majorated by the maximum of three initial numbers. Majorated and non-decreasing sequence always converges.

The next step would be to suppose that the sequence $l_n$ converges to $l$, suppose that $l$ is strictly inferior to the greatest number of initial three numbers, and then obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, showing that $l_n$ converges is not difficult. It's the "next step" I am stuck on.

Comment: I just realized that the middle sequence should also converge (essentially by the same argument). Both the lowest and the middle sequences converge, and their limits should be stable under the process. Therefore, their limits should be 1.